# Symfony serializer returns string instead of array

Tags: php, symfony

I got the following entity field:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="field", type="array", length=65535, nullable=true)
 */
private $field;

/**
 * Set field
 *
 * @param array $field
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function setField($field)
{
    $this->field= $field;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get field
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getField()
{
    return $this->field;
}
```

I receive a JSON with the following field:

```
{"field":["9031234567,9031234568,9031234569"]}
```

and use Symfony serializer code:

```
$filter = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Filter')->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$serializer->deserialize($_POST['data'], Filter::class, 'json', array('object_to_populate' => $filter));
$em->persist($filter);
$em->flush();
```

to save my field into Filter entity. The problem is that in my DB I get this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:32:"9031234567,9031234568,9031234569";} //saved as 1 string
```

while I need this:

```
a:3:{i:0;d:9031234567;i:1;d:9031234568;i:2;d:9031234569;} //every number saved in a separate string
```

Any ideas how to fix that? Thank you.

**UPD** My serializer returns the following:

```
["field":"AppBundle\Entity\Filter":private]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(64) "903255, 345345, 46546, 46546, 46546, 46546, 46546, 46546, 
46546,"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store each field item to the DB, you may use ArrayCollection to deserialize json.

Check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-arrays) topic of Symfony documentation.

I miss your entity annotation.
If you want to store array items into one record, possible to do this:

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->fields = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Add method to add item into entity **(Updated)**:

```
/**
 * @param array $fields
 * @return      $this
 */
public function addFields(array $fields)
{
    $this->fields = $fields;

    return $this;
}
```

When you want to store data into DB you just need:

```
$elementsToDb = ['12345', '67890', '1234567'];
$fields = new Field();
$fields->addFields($elementsToDb);
$this->entityManager->persist($fields);
$this->entityManager->flush($fields);
```

Regards.

Comment: And how to use this addField() method in my code where $serializer->deserialize() is called?

Comment: Could you provide what deserializer return?

Comment: added deserializer return. So what is the point of using serializer if I need manually foreach my array and add it to object? Maybe the reason is that the numbers are stored as string in json (inside quotes)?

Comment: I fixed my answer according to your deserialized data. Check **(Updated)** block.

Comment: Ok, it was fixed by altering json and serving each number with separate quotes each. Thank you for help